# SSRS Formatting

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

So want a row to only be repeated once and size out to all the corresponding rows what's the best way to accomplish this? it would resemble something like this when achieved,

- Choice | PPoints

  - 1_ |__30
    _____29

and so forth, I'm trying to not have to repeat the Choice, 1 value 30 times. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: You could do it with a grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand your post, you are trying to display grouping on fields.

```
Choice|PPoint
1|30
 |29
 |28
.
.
2|30
 |29
.
.
```

You can handle this by creating a Group by using the field Choice.